await _googleSignIn.signIn() doesn't throw an error and doesn't return a user
I am using Macos and flutter and running flutter on my mac.
When the app loads I can see a button that says sign in with google.

I click this button and the oath screen loads in a new window in full screen.
I then click my name then another screen opens and I click continue.
After I click continue it goes back to the macOs flutter app that I
have running.
When I check the logs it doesn't show that it returned
anything by calling that function and there is no errors saying what
went wrong.

I know there is already an account there and even if there wasn't it should still return a google user right?
I am using google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
Here is the minimal code needed. Just create a project then run this function onPressed:
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    
  late GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;

  AuthService() {
    _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      clientId: kIsWeb || defaultTargetPlatform != TargetPlatform.macOS
          ? 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID'
          : null, // For macOS, the clientId can be null since it's handled automatically
    );
  }

show kIsWeb, defaultTargetPlatform, TargetPlatform;
  // Google Sign-In (Handling macOS, Web, iOS/Android separately)
  Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
try {
  print('Starting Google Sign-In');
  UserCredential userCredential;

  if (kIsWeb) {
    // Web Google Sign-In
    print('Google Sign-In for Web');
    GoogleAuthProvider googleProvider = GoogleAuthProvider();
    userCredential = await _auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider);
  } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
    // macOS Google Sign-In using google_sign_in package
    print('Google Sign-In for macOS');
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser == null) {
      print('Google Sign-In aborted by user');
      return null; // User canceled the sign-in
    }

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;
    final OAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  } else {
    // iOS/Android Google Sign-In
    print('Google Sign-In for iOS/Android');
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser == null) {
      print('Google Sign-In aborted by user');
      return null;
    }

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;
    final OAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }

  print('Google Sign-In successful: ${userCredential.user}');
  return userCredential.user;
} catch (e) {
  print("Error during Google Sign-In: $e");
  return null;
}
  }
}

What have I tried:

double checked the keychain is set with my clientID properly
double checked the URL types to make sure they are set up properly
tried different minimal platforms at 11.0 right now tried 10.14 and 10.15 as well.
Assuming that the oath screen wouldn't even show if I didn't have google-info and info.plist not set correctly as having the wrong client id doesn't even open the auth screen.

What can help:

anything, i'd like to know how to solve it myself I tried to debug it, but I don't understand google_sign_ins code and what could be going wrong. Where is it making the http/https call to some google api in order to get my information? Why doesn't flutter give me any sort of error codes: 303, 403, 200 nothing to say that something happened...
let me know of any other package that works for this maybe

Let me know if I should add anything. I guess I can add the button that signs in.
Here is the logs:
flutter: Starting Google Sign-In
flutter: Google Sign-In for macOS
flutter: Google Sign-In aborted by user
the user is always being returned as null.

The official google_sign_in suggests using google_sign_in_web for the web. Please review the documentation and implement all the steps necessary for Google SSO on the Web.
Make sure you have properly set up the Google Cloud console to use Google Sign-in.

I am not having issues with web sign in. Only macos sign in
